# norme of element in cyclotomic fields

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

let $\pi$ a prime in $Z[\zeta_5]$ over  a prime $p$ in $Z$. my quesyion is : can we write the norme $N_{Q(\zeta_5)/Q}$ in term of $p$  ?????

Comment: Also it is quite rare that a prime above $p$ is principal (it happens for $p=5=\prod_{k=1}^4(1-\zeta_5^k)$)

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356710/prime-element-1-zeta-5) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356122/splitting-in-cyclotomic-field-q-zeta-5) on $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$. For the norm see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366363/norm-of-ideals-in-quadratic-number-fields).

Comment: @reuns $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$ has class number $1$.

Comment: really ? Is there a good reason for that or is it just computed from Minkoswki bound as being so @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Yes, really. There are various methods: Minkowski bound, the norm is Euclidean, the analytic class number formula.... @reuns

Answer (score 1):

It's $p^f$ where $f$ is the inertial degree of the prime ideals of
$\Bbb Z[\zeta_5]$ over $p$. This is the least positive integer with
$p^f\equiv1\pmod 5$. See my [previous reply](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3356122/splitting-in-cyclotomic-field-q-zeta-5/3356126#3356126) for more about this $f$.

Comment: so we can say this: $N_{Q(\zeta_5)/Q}(\pi) = p^f$ with $p^f  \equiv 1 [5]$ ??

Comment: That it can't be $-p^f$ isn't obvious

Comment: It's pretty obvious that norms are positive from this field with no real embedding. @reuns

Comment: if we have a condition about $p$ so we can easly get $p^f$, so wi can have $N_{Q(ζ5)/Q}(π)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Can you give me a reference of your answer, that it's $p^f$, thanks a llot